# How can I pass data from one page to another in PHP and Javascript without from?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I pass data from one page to another page in PHP using Javascript without from?

In my blog have a post comment with email Id
and this is routing using foreach loop
problem occur when get email id and comment 
how can i do this? plz help

Comment: you can use ajax to do this! :)

Comment: you can use cookies using PHP ans Js and you can read the values of cookies from PHP and Js

Comment: What is wrong with using a form? What are you actually trying to achieve? (There are lots of ways to pass data and they have different pros and cons, we need to know what problem you are trying to solve, not what solutions you have rejected)

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of client side cookie for this. one page you create cookie and on second page read that cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you dislike with forms is the page reloading on the client side.
If that is the case then you can use ajax requests (maybe with the help of a framework like jQuery, or pure javascript with the `xmlHTTPRequest()`).

Alternatively you can use cookies, but it's not what they really are for.

If you don't mind the page reloading, you can also use HTTP GET requests with javascript :

```
location.assign("http://www.my_site.com/index.php?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store data in [Web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp) if the data doesn't necessarily need to be processed in PHP.

You will need to have a backup system in cookies though for the older browsers that do not support his.